# SourceSafe Visual Web Developer 2010

Tags: visual-web-developer, plugins

Does anyone know if there is a SourceSafe plugin for Visual Web Developer 2010

Answer (score 3):

If there is...don't use it. Try looking up SVN solutions, SourceSafe is just horrible.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Brian Harry's blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/vs-2010-and-sourcesafe/) plugin delivered with SourceSafe 2005 works in Visual Studio 2010 after installing a hotfix (linked in the blog post).

But I'm not sure if express editions like Visual Web Developer are supported.